# Issue with coord cartesian in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

When trying to use coord_cartesian(expand = c(0, 0)), I receive the following error:

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(disp, wt)) +
    geom_point() +
    geom_smooth() +
    coord_cartesian(expand = c(0, 0))
```

**Error in if (!expand) { : the condition has length > 1**

Any clue about how to solve this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: expand takes a boolean value (TRUE of FALSE): `expand:  
If TRUE, the default, adds a small expansion factor to the limits to ensure that data and axes don't overlap. If FALSE, limits are taken exactly from the data or xlim/ylim.`

Comment: Thanks, what about if I what to change the limits? e.g., instead of c(0, 0) c(1, 1)

Comment: You can add `xlim` and `ylim` in the `coord_cartesian`

Comment: Do you want `coord_cartesian(expand = FALSE)` for no expansion?